# For loop misunderstanding in java

Tags: java

i come from python 3 now learning java.(this is part of my first (try at a) program in java)

**Code:**

```
int var2 = input.nextInt();

        int i = 0;

        for ( i != var2);
```

**Result:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>
> problems:     The method i(int) is undefined for the type Main    Syntax
>
> error on token "!=", ( expected   Syntax error, insert "; ) Statement"
>
> to complete ForStatement
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:18)

Comment: Java uses curly braces, not indentation, to mark blocks. Also, is that *all* of your code? If so, there is a lot missing in order for it to compile. Plus, your `for` loop is totally broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is a control statement, but you still need some operations for that statement to exercise.

The format is

```
for (some expression controlling the number of times to do something) {
   some commands to run.
}
```

Currently your for loop lacks the block of commands to run

In addition, the format of the controlling expression is typically shown in three parts

```
for (run this first; check this each time before running the block; run this after each run of the block) {
   ... commands ...
}
```

Note that the semicolons are not optional but the actual items within each place separated by the semicolons are

A typical for loop might look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.println("number " + i);
}
```

Where before the loop is run, the variable `i` is set to zero.
Before each execution of `System.out.println("number " + i);` it is verified that `i < 10` evaluates to true.
After each time `System.out.println("number " + i);` is executed, the variable `i` is incremented through the operation `i++`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right syntax

```
for(initialization; booleanExpression; update) {
    //statements
}
```

Example

```
for(int x = 0; x <10; x++) { 
    System.out.println(x); 
}
```

Relatively modern foreach

```
for(data_type variable : array | collection){
// Statements
}
```

Example

```
int arr[]={12,13,14,44};  
for(int i:arr){
    System.out.println(i);  
}
```